# Django Admin Filtering a OneToOneField

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to built an app to manage some network equipment we have. But I need help to figure out how to create my models for the switches and network card.

So I created 3 models :

1. Network card linked with a foreignKey to an equipment. For instance server-dc01 has one network card.
2. Switch, this is for my switches.
3. SwitchPort, here I can create ports and link them to a switch. So if a switch has 24 ports I need to create 24 switch ports and link all of them to my switch. A bit annoying. I don't know if it's the best.

Here are the model I have for now :

```
class NetworkCard(models.Model):
    equipment = models.ForeignKey('Equipment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attached_to_port = models.OneToOneField('SwitchPorts', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Switch(Equipment):
    number_of_ports = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class SwitchPorts(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    switch = models.ForeignKey('Switch', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So, in admin, I can add a Network card to an equipment, and "plug" that network card to a switch port. But, of course, when I have 10 switches with 48 ports, the dropdown select is too long. I tried the raw_id_field but it's not really user friendly neither.

What I want is something like this in admin :
- A dropdown select where I can choose the switch
- A second dropdown where I can choose the port on the switch selected before, showing only the free ports on that switch.

Therefore, my questions are :

- is my way with a model for switch port good ?
- if yes, how to get the two select working as I want ?
- if no, what should I do ?

I also tried to not have the switch port model. So a card is only linked to a switch. In this scenario I can add a number (in a PositiveSmallIntegerField) to define on which port on the switch the card is plugged. Very user friendly... BUT I need to add information about vlan on my port on the switch side.

Any ideas guys ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). This package lets you chain models together so that in the admin, selecting the one AJAX loads the next selectable option.

As for your models - I would not use string representations. You can just use the models instead (i.e. `switch = models.ForeignKey(Switch, ...)`. Lastly, I'm not sure about inheriting `Equipment` unless you made sure it's an abstract class (which I can't see).

Comment: This Django-smart-selects sounds interesting. I would give it a try after reading.

Comment: For the second part of your answer, I don't get what you mean by "string representations".  And switches are inherited from Equipment because I have other type of equipment (switch, router, server, workstation...)

Comment: @vjuluss What I mean is you can use the object `Equipment` instead of `'Equipment'`. Also, if you are inheriting from an abstract base class that is fine for `Switch`. If this answered your question, you can press the check mark under the down arrow for others to see this answer satisfied your question. Best of luck!

Comment: Ok I get it now. I will read about Django-smart-select and try it, then I'll close this question. Thanks a lot !